# Mulitiple line chart display with zoom in & zoom out features on python

Tags: python, charts

I am trying to build a user interface to show multiple line charts with zoom in & out features on python. Some similar work would be like the chart display on Finance.yahoo.com:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxSzJ.png)

For example, the image above shows three charts ( though some of them are bar type ), the index data, the volume data and the corresponding technical indicator data. The user can either drag the chart to left or right to view older or newer data , or click on the -/+ button to change the time span ( window to cover 1 year / 3 years, etc ). The three charts

I am wondering if there is any package on python that would help to build such a display. Thank you!

Comment: Did you use search? Examle this: http://matplotlib.org/

Answer (score 0):

May be try [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com), which has a Python edition.